# rails-pry failure to create breakpoint: before_session hook failed: NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry, pry-rails

I'm using `rails-pry` to create a breakpoint with a `binding.pry` statement. This has worked just fine for just about ever. However now there's this fun new error message I'm not even sure how to being debugging the debugger:

```
before_session hook failed: NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
usr/local/bundle/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pager.rb:116:in `block in write'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
```

The result is the `binding.pry` statement is ignored and the code I intent to inspect continues to run.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example ruby script that exhibits the behavior? If you run `Readline.readline("")` in an irb console does it work? https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/v0.12.2/lib/pry/pager.rb#L116

Comment: According to the doc, Readline.readline method returns `nil` when you have empty line and enter `EOF` (Ctrl-D), so maybe you are sending Ctrl-D accidentally. And other than @spike's suggestion I would try to see if you haven't upgraded ruby or your OS recently, since Readline is a module which interfaces to the GNU readline.